# Ad hoc distribution issues with iTunes 10+ (Xcode 3.1.4, Leopard)

Tags: iphone, xcode, itunes, osx-leopard, stress

I have an old version of Xcode so have been unable to create an .ipa file. I also only have leopard installed as the company I work for does not wish to purchase an upgrade so close to a new version being released.

The issue I am having is that when I drag the .mobileprovision file into iTunes that seems to be ok and it does ask if I wish to replace it. When I drag the .app file into iTunes it states 'An provisioning profile named "embedded.mobileprovision" already exists on this computer. Do you wish to replace it?'. If I click Yes then nothing happens.

I had this working on an old iTunes version this morning then updated as a client was having issues importing the .app file. Are all ad hoc distributions done with .ipa files now?

Basic steps I have been following:

2) Unzip the contents of “Sample.zip”

3) On Mac you will have two files, on PC you will have one file and one folder. These will be called “Sample.app” and “XXXX.mobileprovision”. The XXXX refers to whatever name the developer chose for their Adhoc profile (I use Andrews_Adhoc_DP).

4) Open iTunes.

5) Select both “Sample.app” and XXXX.mobileprovision and drag them to the Library panel

6) In your Applications pane you should now see the application which can be synced with your phone.

**tldr; Can ad hoc installations still be done with a .mobileprovision file and a .app folder?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note to self and anyone who has the same issue:

In the info.plist file "Application requires iPhone environment" should be set to true. (got unticked for some reason)